# I could not retrieve xml attrubutes from xml inputs

Tags: xml, xslt

```
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <p:transformOutput xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects">
                <p:objectSet>
                    <p:objects>
                        <p:object>
                            <p:objectAttributes>
                                <p:objectType>a</p:objectType>
                                <p:attribute name="x">F600</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="y">A100</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="z">D400</p:attribute>
                            </p:objectAttributes>
                        </p:object>
                        <p:object>
                            <p:objectAttributes>
                                <p:objectType>b</p:objectType>
                                <p:attribute name="x">F600</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="y">C300</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="z">B200</p:attribute>
                            </p:objectAttributes>
                        </p:object>
                        <p:object>
                            <p:objectAttributes>
                                <p:objectType>b</p:objectType>
                                <p:attribute name="x">a</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="y">A100</p:attribute>
                                <p:attribute name="z">B200</p:attribute>
                            </p:objectAttributes>
                        </p:object>
                    </p:objects>
                </p:objectSet>

            <ns1:Templates>
                <ns1:Template>
                    <ns1:System_Class>a</ns1:System_Class>
                    <ns1:System_Table>A100</ns1:System_Table>
                    <ns1:System_Attribute>aA</ns1:System_Attribute>
                </ns1:Template>
                <ns1:Template>
                    <ns1:System_Class>b</ns1:System_Class>
                    <ns1:System_Table>B200</ns1:System_Table>
                    <ns1:System_Attribute>bB</ns1:System_Attribute>
                </ns1:Template>
            </ns1:Templates>
```

xsl

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects" xmlns:ns1="http://cfpe/export/objects"
            exclude-result-prefixes="p">
            <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

            <xsl:template match="/p:transformOutput">
                <objects>
                    <xsl:for-each select="p:transformOutput/p:objectSet/p:objects/p:object">
                        <object type="{p:objectAttributes/p:objectType}">
                            <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="p:objectAttributes/*" />
                            <xsl:variable name="matching-template" select="p:transformOutput/ns1:Templates/ns1:Template[ns1:System_Class=$attributes and ns1:System_Table=$attributes]" />
                            <template>
                               <xsl:value-of select="tns:System_Attribute"/>
                            </template>
                        </object>
                    </xsl:for-each>     
                </objects>
            </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

matching-template doesn't seem to find the value path. I was trying to compare  System_Class if exists in objectAttributes and get the System_Attribute from  if the value of the System_Attribute doesn't exist in the objectAttributes

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSL Tokenize the codition attribute with xml input file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921099/xsl-tokenize-the-codition-attribute-with-xml-input-file)

Comment: it still doesn't out put anything

Comment: You input XML is not well-formed, by the way. It is missing a closing `p:transformOutput` tag, and also missing the namespace declaration for the `ns1` prefix. It would help if you amended your question to fix the XML. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start off by matching on the root element `p:transformOutput` like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/p:transformOutput">
```

But then you do a `xsl:for-each` which also includes the root element

```
<xsl:for-each select="p:transformOutput/p:objectSet/p:objects/p:object">
```

You are already positioned on a `p:transformOutput` so this will be looking for a child element, which won't exist. You need to change it to this;

```
<xsl:for-each select="p:objectSet/p:objects/p:object">
```

You later refer to it again in the `matching-template` variable

```
<xsl:variable name="matching-template" 
     select="p:transformOutput/ns1:Templates/ns1:Template[ns1:System_Class=$attributes and ns1:System_Table=$attributes]" />
```

But at this point you are in the `xsl:for-each` construct, and so positioned on an `p:object`. You need to make the xpath expression an absolute expression to allow you search from the root again.

```
<xsl:variable name="matching-template" 
     select="/p:transformOutput/ns1:Templates/ns1:Template[ns1:System_Class=$attributes and ns1:System_Table=$attributes]"/>
```

Finally, you try to get the `System_Attribute` like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tns:System_Attribute"/>
```

But you are still positioned on a `p:object` at this point. You need to include the `matching-template` variable in the expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$matching-template/ns1:System_Attribute"/>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects" xmlns:ns1="http://cfpe/export/objects" exclude-result-prefixes="p">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/p:transformOutput">
        <objects>
            <xsl:for-each select="p:objectSet/p:objects/p:object">
                <object type="{p:objectAttributes/p:objectType}">
                    <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="p:objectAttributes/*"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="matching-template" select="/p:transformOutput/ns1:Templates/ns1:Template[ns1:System_Class=$attributes and ns1:System_Table=$attributes]"/>
                    <template>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$matching-template/ns1:System_Attribute"/>
                    </template>
                </object>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </objects>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```